# Is there a M.2 NVME extension cable? (+ considerations on using them)

Tags: laptop, ssd, cable, computer-building, nvme

I am looking for an NVME extension cable, because there is hardware position conflict, and I would like to avoid using hacky solutions such as taping my NVME SSD on a surface I'm not too sure would be safe.

I am trying to modify my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 to have both NVME Slot and SATA installed, as I need as much storage packed on my hardware.
I have seen Graphics card extension cable, and I thought there might be one for NVME slot.

I have been searching for this extension, and I only find either PCIe extension or some shaddy product I am unsure if it's safe.
If it exist, what keyword should I use to search for them, or example product I can look into?

Comment: just a thought, if you can't have both SSD and NVMe physically installed at the same time, have you considered that the system won't allow it? i.e. only one or the other will actually work?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have. It's just a physical constraint. In software it works. As I said, `I would like to avoid using hacky solutions such as taping my NVME SSD on a surface`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extenders do exist, such as this
[Sintech M.2 NVME Extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DZCCGJN)
which got good reviews, and even in the comments one user chained
two of them with success.

I don't know this product and I'm not recommending it,
it's just a proof of concept.
I'm just saying that such good products do exist, and searching
on a site where user reviews are available is safer.

[image]

Comment: Be careful this is a referral link. Instead, you can search for " Sintech M.2 NVME Extender,NGFF M-Key PCIe SSD Extention Card with Anti-electromagnetic Foiled Cable 20CMS (Silver Cable) " on amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that I used for a not identical but similar situation (migrating  data on an M2 drive to another M2 drive.
I bought a m2/sata 2.5 converter. Plugged the M2 into the converter and connected it the SATA cables. I didn't notice any performance decrease and it did the job. Maybe this will give you the room you need. The converter wasn't expensive either.

Comment: Although a different answer entirely, this could work, but the drawback is that you're limited to M.2 SATA and be not able to use M.2 NVME